# How can I import new songs into my Clementine library?

Tags: clementine

After I've installed Clementine and imported (for the first time) my complete music library it seems to be impossible to add more songs.

I can however effortlessly add songs to a playlist - but not to the big library.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Open the preferences dialog box through tools menu.

[image]

Click on "Music Library" in sidebar of preferences dialog box.

[image]

Hare you can add more folders to your music library. Clementine will scan these folders on every startup for new songs and will add them automatically to your music library.

Comment: This is not the right answer... It does not add the folder to the existing library folder, it just extends the library view with the new folder, but the files are not moved into the library in the right place...

Answer (score 0):

- OK, after much struggle I know the answer to this. The problem is that imagine that one downloads an album from a source which you would prefer to have organised in your music folder.
- Move the album(s) to a convenient folder and then go to preferences and add this folder temporarily to your sources - preferences - music library - add new folder.
- After this you can check that Clementine sees the new album by going to show - added today.
- Now add these new albums to a playlist and select all. Right click and go to organise files.
- This will give you a way to organise the files into your original music folder giving you the (default) option to delete the originals. (By the way this is the way to copy files to another folder remembering NOT to delete the originals).
- In this case you do not wish to keep the originals and yet if you do keep them you will notice that after the organise you have two copies of each song - one in each location.
- Now if you manually go back to your temporary folder you can delete them and Clementine will automatically update the library to having only the one copy.

There you go finished, now you can add the songs back into a playlist so that you can edit the information, I like to check that the genre is correct etc. hope this helps